# Fonts look washed out in QT Quick on Mac

Tags: macos, qt-quick

When running Qt Quick apps (QML) on my Mac, some fonts look really washed out. Here is a screenshot of the Qt "gallery" demo:

[image]

My own QML app has the same problem when I run it directly (via the code generated by Qt Creator). When I view it in qmlscene, the fonts look fine though. Strangely, the fonts of the gallery demo look bad when running the executable as well as in qmlscene. What can I do to get nice fonts?

I am using Qt 5.1.1, and a fresh install of the Qt SDK.

Comment: Did you try 5.2 beta? Seems this is an OpenGL related issue. What is the mac os version you use?

Comment: @Dasun: This is on Lion. I try 5.2 when I find some time. Thanks!